# spring cache expire using bean property

Tags: spring, caching, spring-cache

Is there a way of indicating to expire/evict the cache object based on a property of the POJO cached.

In below code, it caches `Foo` instance. Foo class has a `expiresIn` property
class Foo {
    Date expiresIn;
}

I want to hint to spring to expire the cache based on the value of `expiresIn` property of cached element. Is this feasible?

```java
@Cacheable("my-cache-key")
    Foo getCachedToken(String userName, String password) throws AuthException
```

My Cache.xml is below:

```
<cache:annotation-driven/>

<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.support.CompositeCacheManager">
    <property name="cacheManagers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="mapCacheManager"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="mapCacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheManager">
    <property name="cacheNames">
        <list>
            <value>my-cache-key</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you missed the section name [How can I set the TTL/TTI/Eviction policy/XXX feature?](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#cache-specific-config) from the reference guide.

This is a cache infrastructure abstraction; It's not a cache provider. `ConcurrentMapCacheManager` is a very simple implementation we provide for testing purposes or for super-simple use cases. If you need an eviction policy, choose a caching library that does support that. Ehcache, Guava or Hazelcast come to mind. All of them have a `CacheManager` implementation.