How to set Expiration/TTL(Time to Live) for couchbase documents using spring-boot-starter-data-couchbase and spring-boot-starter-cache?
I am working on an OTP (one-time password) provider microservice and I want to cache the OTPs in Couchbase and retrieve them for a given key. I am able to achieve this using the following pieces of code. But I am not able to implement one final feature, which is, the OTP should be short-lived and should get automatically evicted from the cache after a certain configurable interval.
I am using the following dependencies -
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-couchbase</artifactId>
        </dependency>

and I have configured a CacheConfig as follows -
@Configuration
public class CacheConfig {

    @Value("${couchbase.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${couchbase.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${couchbase.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${couchbase.bucket}")
    private String bucket;

    public static final String CACHE_NAME ="otp-cache";

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "disconnect")
    public Cluster cluster() {
        return Cluster.connect(url, username, password);
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return CouchbaseCacheManager.create(new SimpleCouchbaseClientFactory(cluster(), bucket, null));
    }
}

finally in my service class, where i generate the OTP, I am using the @Cacheable annotation as follows -
@Cacheable(cacheNames = CacheConfig.CACHE_NAME, key = "'provider_'+#key")
    @Override
    public Integer generateOTP(String key) {
        StringBuilder generatedOTP = new StringBuilder();
        SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
        LOGGER.info("generating OTP for provider(not from cache) - "+key);
        try {
            secureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance(secureRandom.getAlgorithm());
            for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH_OF_OTP; i++) {
                generatedOTP.append(secureRandom.nextInt(9));
            }
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            LOGGER.error("exception occurred in generating OTP");
        }
        return Integer.parseInt(generatedOTP.toString());
    }

I have come across some solutions which suggests using the @CacheEvict annotation with a @Scheduled method, but it will clear the entire cache and not just expired entries.
I have also tried wrapping the response of the @Cacheable method in a serializable object and used the @Document(expiryExpression = and @Expiry annotation, but that does not work either, additionally, I get some class cast exception when the object is fetched from the cache and spring tries to deserialize it to the pojo class.
I also see this property using my IDE's auto-suggestion in application-properties file spring.cache.couchbase.expiration=, but this doesn't work either.
How do I set an expiration time for each otp cached in the couchbase bucket?

For a lifetime of 60 minutes, use
CouchbaseCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig().entryExpiry(Duration.ofMinutes(60))
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/reference/couchbase/caching.html

accepting this answer as this is more in line with my original question. keeping my answer as well, as it is also solving the same problem, albeit with a different approach

here's the cacheManager bean updated code which works with my solution -
 @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        CouchbaseCacheManager.CouchbaseCacheManagerBuilder builder = CouchbaseCacheManager.CouchbaseCacheManagerBuilder
                .fromConnectionFactory(new SimpleCouchbaseClientFactory(cluster(), bucket, null));
        builder.withCacheConfiguration(CACHE_NAME, CouchbaseCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig().entryExpiry(Duration.ofSeconds(expiryInSec)));
        return builder.build();
    }


Got from some references that spring @Cachebale does not support expiration time (https://stackoverflow.com/a/29191001/11259999 ), so completely removed the Spring caching mechanism(removed the spring-boot-starter-cache dependency itself)  and replaced it by explicit calls to Couchbase to read/remove objects from the cache.
here are the changes in implementation

created a POJO to persist the OTP in the Couchbase bucket

@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class OTP implements Serializable {
    String providerId;
    int otp;


}


changes in Service -

 @Autowired
    CacheConfig cacheConfig;

 public Integer getOrGenerateOTP(String key) {
        try {
            Cluster cluster = cacheConfig.cluster();
            if (cluster.bucket(cacheConfig.getBucket()).defaultCollection().exists(key).exists()) {
                GetResult getResult = cluster.bucket(cacheConfig.getBucket()).defaultCollection().get(key);
                if (getResult.contentAsObject().containsKey("otp"))
                    return Integer.parseInt("" + getResult.contentAsObject().get("otp"));
            } else {
                StringBuilder generatedOTP = new StringBuilder();
                SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
                LOGGER.info("generating OTP for provider(not from cache) - " + key);
                try {
                    secureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance(secureRandom.getAlgorithm());
                    for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH_OF_OTP; i++) {
                        generatedOTP.append(secureRandom.nextInt(9));
                    }
                } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
                    LOGGER.error("exception occurred in generating OTP");
                }
               
                Temporal startTm = Instant.now();
                Temporal endTm = Instant.now().plus(Period.ofDays(2));
                Duration d= Duration.ofSeconds(10); // can be used in place of Duration.between(startTm, endTm)
                cluster.bucket(cacheConfig.getBucket())
                        .defaultCollection()
                        .upsert(key, new OTP(key, Integer.parseInt(generatedOTP.toString())),
                                UpsertOptions.upsertOptions().expiry(d));


                return Integer.parseInt(generatedOTP.toString());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getStackTrace());
        }
        return null;
    }

 public void clearOtp(String key) {
        try {
            Cluster cluster = cacheConfig.cluster();
            GetResult getResult = cluster.bucket(cacheConfig.getBucket()).defaultCollection().get(key);
            cluster.bucket(cacheConfig.getBucket()).defaultCollection().remove(key);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getStackTrace());
        }

    }

This solution works and serves my purpose but if anyone has any work-around that works along with the spring caching mechanism, please add the answer here as well. Also, not sure how does the performance of the two approaches compares to each other, so any answer clarifying that is also welcome.
